# Nfc not required in app(Google Play)

Tags: android, nfc

I have an application that may or may not work with NFC. I have added these lines to manifest:

`<manifest ...>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
</manifest>`

When I search for the application in google play, the message continues: "Your device is not compatible with this version"

I have verified that the NFCAdapter is not null, I have requested the pertinent permissions directly in execution ... but that message continues to come out.

**APORTACION**:

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.app.app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name=".timer.UploadService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.uploaddata.ui.UploadDataService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".main.ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".p1.ui.class1"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_class1"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".p2.ui.class2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_class2"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/class2ActivityTheme"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".p3.ui.class3"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_class3"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".p4.ui.class4"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_class4"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".p5.ui.class5"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_class5"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I too am facing this issue

Comment: Hi @ivarajet, my problem ended up being impatience. I waited for one to two days and the problem was solved. It is possible that google servers did not resolve the request well and took a little longer to update. I really do not know what the reason was but my app is already working. Code problem was not. Make a post, expose your code and I will try to look at it :)

Comment: Adding android:required="false" for both "uses-feature" and "uses-permission" solved the issue

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" android:required="false" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is not a bad code. I waited for one to two days and the problem was solved. It is possible that google servers did not resolve the request well and took a little longer to update. I really do not know what the reason was but my app is already working :)